# Responsive design and browser zoom - why happens like this?

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, media-queries, zooming

I have very annoying problem, which I don't know how to handle.
I am building a responsive layout in wordpress using media queries defined in px.
I think I've used the proper meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

My question is why zooming with the browser, media queries affects the layout? I don't know whether this is a normal behavior for a responsive layout and media queries.

I want to get rid of this especially when zooming out - without entering the queries for bigger width screens. I've investigated some of the popular responsive websites like yahoo and mozilla, but their layout on zoom out does not rearrange.
Hope my question is clear and you can help me.

Comment: If you mean the browser thinks the screen size is changing when you zoom, yes, this is normal. With a window 600px wide and zoomed in to 200%, the page acts like it's 300px wide. Does that answer your question? Otherwise, you may have to illustrate your problem with a demo.

Comment: Yeah I understand that the browser acts the way you explained, but is this a normal behavior because I can't observe the same resizing when I zoom out popular responsive websites like yahoo or mozilla